# Table cells unintentionally change size after a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically building a table using JS but, for some reason, after clicking on the `btn_dropdown0` "button", which is supposed to hide and show the `tbody`, the button itself gets slightly moved left and right. The reason for this, after inspecting my code behavior, is that the two blank `th` are resizing, probably due to the fact that when the `tbody` is visibile, the cells on the row below contain some data and so they get stretched.
This is my table replicated and the jQuery handling the effects:

```js
$('#btn_dropdown0').click(function() {
 if($(this).css('transform') == 'matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0)'){
  $(this).css({'transform': ''});
  $('#tbody0').hide();
 }else{
  $(this).css({'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'});
  $('#tbody0').show();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-hover text-center">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Bangkok</th>
                <th scope="col">Milan</th>
                <th scope="col">Flight type: international</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down" id="btn_dropdown0"></i></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody0" style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>15:00</td>
                <td>16:00</td>
                <td>Supported airplanes: 1,4,5</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info">Reserve</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>22:00</td>
                <td>23:00</td>
                <td>Supported airplanes: 1,4,5</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info">Reserve</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: please check below answer !

Answer (score 0):

Add width to `th`, it will remain in same position. As there is no width to `th` so it is taking according to content size in it. Now when you click it is flickering due to scrollbar. Check it in full page mode.

```js
$('#btn_dropdown0').click(function() {
 if($(this).css('transform') == 'matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0)'){
  $(this).css({'transform': ''});
  $('#tbody0').hide();
 }else{
  $(this).css({'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'});
  $('#tbody0').show();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-hover text-center">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">Bangkok</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">Milan</th>
                <th scope="col" width="45%">Flight type: international</th>
                <th scope="col" width="10%"></th>
                <th scope="col" width="10%"></th>
                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down" id="btn_dropdown0"></i></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody0" style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>15:00</td>
                <td>16:00</td>
                <td>Supported airplanes: 1,4,5</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info">Reserve</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>22:00</td>
                <td>23:00</td>
                <td>Supported airplanes: 1,4,5</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info">Reserve</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```